# GWT Development Mode in Eclipse leaving opening too many sessions

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I've had this problem for a couple days now.  After about an hour or two of running my GWT dev server without restarting it, my "Development Mode" tab is showing many sessions remaining open.  Open or at least it's showing them as active.  I've seen as much as 8.  When this is happening Eclipse runs very sluggish, and my application runs extremely slow (mostly the front end).  I'm doing lots of browser refreshes and server reloads but nothing like opening 2nd browsers or running multiple tabs.  The only way to close these sessions is to do stop my server and start it again.  Before a few days ago, it seemed to only keep one open or maybe two sometimes.  I'd never seen three unless I had multiple tabs or browsers running dev mode.

After talking to my two co-workers, who use pretty much the same environment as me.  One of them has always has this issue, and for years has just been periodically restarting his server every couple hours to fix it.  The other's works fine.

I'm running FF.
Our GWT application only has one module.

Does anybody know how to remedy this or how to limit the # of sessions?  I haven't made any config changes to eclipse or changed any preferences that I'm aware recently that would have caused this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a known issue with Firefox:
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7648

Comment: Thanks! Yea I recall I did upgrade from FF 5 -> to 20 recently.  My co-worker who has this problem is on 15, the one who doesn't is on a way older version.  Downgrading...